# Mongoose pre hook or method not working with findOneAndUpdate Method

Tags: mongoose

I am attempting to implement an incrementing counter.   I store the number in the 'projects' collection and attempt to retrieve and increment by 1 when inserting a new document in the 'issues' collection.

I have tried this a couple of different ways and haven't had success.   I could acheive this easily by simply getting the number and incrementing it by 1 and sending it with the form submit, but then I wouldn't be learning.    From some other answers I have seen, the problem appears to the middleware is not aware of the document on a findOneAndUpdate query operation.

Here is the first .pre operation I tried without success.

```
.pre('save', function(next) {
 counter = Project.findOneAndUpdate({_id: this.project}, {$inc: { numberSeq: 1} });
 console.log(counter);
 this.number = counter.numberSeq;
 next();
});
```

Next, I gave this a try.   Everything seems to work from the console output, except for the document updating.

```
.pre('save', function(next){
  console.log('attempting to get next num ');
  Project.findOneAndUpdate({_id: this.project}, {$inc: { numberSeq: 1} }, function(error, counter)   {
    console.log('project is ' + counter.project);
    console.log('number seq is ' + counter.numberSeq);
    this.number = counter.numberSeq;
    console.log('next num sequence is: ' + this.number);
      next();
  });

});
```

Lastly, here is the method I attempted to use.

```
IssueSchema.methods.getNextNumber = function(project) {
    Project.findOneAndUpdate({_id: project}, {$inc: { numberSeq: 1} }, function(error, counter)   {
        if(error) {
            return error;
          }
          console.log(counter.numberSeq);
        return counter.numberSeq;
    });
};
```

And used like this.   It works, almost, but the update seems to finish before the method delivers the next number and number ends up being undefined.  I tried a few ways to make it synchronous, to no avail

```
    var issue = new Issues({
      title: req.body.title,
      description: req.body.description,
      fields: req.body.fields,
      project: req.body.project,
      created_by: req.user || req.body.created_by,
      type: req.body.type,

    });

    issue.number = issue.getNextNumber();

    issue.save(function(err, result) {
      if (err) {
        return res.status(409).send({message: 'There was an error creating the issue: ' + err});
      }
      console.log(result);
      res.send({message: 'New issue created', result: result});
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I kept throwing darts at the wall until something finally stuck.   Turns out it was pretty simple and I simply needed to assign the number within the callback and then throw next.

```
.pre('save', function(next) {
  Project.findOne({_id: this.project}).select('numberSeq').exec(function(err, doc) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
      this.number = doc.numberSeq;
      next();
    });
})
.post('save', function(doc) {
  Project.update({_id: doc.project}, {$inc:  {numberSeq: 1}}, function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  });
});
```